# Boost Log: variable is not a member of ‘boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial’

Tags: c++, boost, g++, boost-log

I'd like to switch over different `boost::log` severity levels using a single variable to control lots of `BOOST_TRIVIAL_LOG(lvl)` calls.

```
// Class header
const boost::log::trivial::severity_level _LVL_DEBUG;

// Class ctor initialize list
#ifdef FOO_MACRO
        _LVL_DEBUG(boost::log::trivial::severity_level::info)
#else
        _LVL_DEBUG(boost::log::trivial::severity_level::debug)
#endif

// Class method
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(_LVL_DEBUG) << "Foo bar";
```

But when g++ compiling I obtain

> error: ‘_LVL_DEBUG’ is not a member of ‘boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial’

I'd like to know where I'm missing the point.

#### Edit 1

Same output with `boost::log::trivial::info` (or other level ofc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're trying to do. `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(x)` expands the severity level `x` to `boost::log::trivial::severity_level::x`, where `severity_level` is an enum and `x` is supposed to be a value of that enum.

If you want to control severity levels in compile time then all you have to do is to define your macro like this:

```
#ifdef FOO_MACRO
#define _LVL_DEBUG info
#else
#define _LVL_DEBUG debug
#endif
```

Then you use it in logging statements like this:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(_LVL_DEBUG) << "Foo bar";
```

If you want runtime control then you can no longer use `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` and have to use `BOOST_LOG_SEV` or other macros that take the severity level directly. This also means you would have to create and manage loggers yourself.